# par() options pin and oma in R

Tags: r

I'm having a problem using the `par` option `oma` to set a plot-wide title, when I have specified plot sizes using `pin`.  The `oma` title is way way up (seems outside of the `oma` range) when `pin` is used; when `pin` is commented out (as below) the `oma` title location is visually appealing.  I've tried rotating the sequence of `par` options, thinking one might be over-riding the others, but no luck.  Code is below.  Clues appreciated!  Thanks, Tom

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # 1X2 graphs
par(oma=c(0,0,5,0))  # top has 5 lines of space 
par(mar=c(4,4,2,1)+.1)  # margin lines
#par(pin=c(1.9,1.9))  # plot areas for graphs

# plot 1
plot(rnorm(n=20),col="olivedrab",pch=19,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0),xlim=c(0,20),ylab="",xlab="")
mtext("Observation No.",side=1,line=3)
mtext("Random variate",side=2,line=3)
mtext("Olivedrab Plot",side=3,line=2,cex=1.5)

# plot 2
plot(rnorm(n=20),col="olivedrab2",pch=19,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0),xlim=c(0,20),ylab="",xlab="")
mtext("Observation No.",side=1,line=3)
mtext("Random variate",side=2,line=3)
mtext("Olivedrab Plot",side=3,line=2,cex=1.5)

mtext("Army Olive Drab Plots",side=3,line=3,cex=2,outer=TRUE)  # add outer label
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not described what you want to see, only what code produces something you do not like. Guessing that you want to see `mtext` produce a "main title" that is further away from the outer edge of the graphics device (closer to the graphs)  I suggest you use a negative line number for placement. As the help page says, 'line' specifies "starting at 0 counting outwards" (although I was unable to find a description of where we should expect that zero-line to be.)

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # 1X2 graphs
par(oma=c(0,0,5,0))  # top has 5 lines of space 
par(mar=c(4,4,2,1)+.1)  # margin lines
par(pin=c(1.9,1.9))  # plot areas for graphs

# plot 1
plot(rnorm(n=20),col="olivedrab",pch=19,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0),xlim=c(0,20),ylab="",xlab="")
mtext("Observation No.",side=1,line=3)
mtext("Random variate",side=2,line=3)
mtext("Olivedrab Plot",side=3,line=2,cex=1.5)

# plot 2
plot(rnorm(n=20),col="olivedrab2",pch=19,ylim=c(-2.0,2.0),xlim=c(0,20),ylab="",xlab="")
mtext("Observation No.",side=1,line=3)
mtext("Random variate",side=2,line=3)
mtext("Olivedrab Plot",side=3,line=2,cex=1.5)

mtext("Army Olive Drab Plots",side=3,line=-3,cex=2,outer=TRUE)
```